# Value error in plotting a time series data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to make a bar/count plot for a time series data:

```
avg_curr1 = df[df['name'] == 'name1'].groupby(["Week of the Month", "Month"]).count()
print(avg_curr1)
```

Output:

```py
Week of the Month  Month  col1  col2  col3  col3  col4
1                  10     1055  1055  1055  1055  1055
                   11     842   842   842   842   842
                   12     789   789   789   789   789
2                  10     668   668   668   668   668
                   11     846   846   846   846   846
                   12     802   802   802   802   802
3                  10     752   752   752   752   752
                   11     684   684   684   684   684
                   12     134   134   134   134   134
4                  10     447   447   447   447   447
                   11     462   462   462   462   462
                   12     386   386   386   386   386
5                  9      58    58    58    58    58
                   10     265   265   265   265   265
                   11     140   140   140   140   140
                   12     230
```

so basically, these are the values count for the last three months, that has been grouped into each weeks.

I then tried:

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
ax = sns.countplot(x="avg_curr1", data=avg_curr1, hue = 'Month')
```

which threw a value error.

Am I aggregating the data incorrectly? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Modified the graph to get the output:

```
avg_curr1 = df[df['name'] == 'name1'].groupby(["Week of the Month", "Month"]).count().reset_index().sort_values(by = "name",ascending=False)
data = pd.concat([avg_curr1], axis=0)
ax = sns.pointplot("Week of the Month", "name", data = data, hue = "Month", markers = "H")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze count for each week of month then you should use barplot instead of countplot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
avg_curr1=pd.read_excel(INPATH)
avg_curr1=avg_curr1.ffill(axis = 0)
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
s=sns.barplot(x='Week of the Month',y='col1',data=avg_curr1, hue ='Month')
```

[image]